# Is it possible to use level value instead of number in bunyan log messages?

Tags: node.js, bunyan

Bunyan-node logs are printed (to stdout) with numeric log levels, as defined in the bunyan doc (https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#levels )

```
{ ... , level: 10, .... }
```

Is it possible to print them with the actual value, in this case-

```
{ ... , level: "trace", .... }
```

?

Comment: If you insist not to use number, how about define constant like TRACE = 10 and use it ( it will give level: TRACE)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible using `bunyan`, as per the document `level` in core-fields.

> level: Required. Integer. Added by Bunyan. Cannot be overridden. See the "Levels" section.

https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#core-fields

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: **Yes**

See how they got it implemented in their test case.

```
var bunyan = require('../lib/bunyan');
var log1 = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'log1',
    streams: [
        {
            path: __dirname + '/level.test.log1.log',
            level: 'info' /* Using word */
        }
    ]
});
```

**Reference:** 
https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/blob/master/test/level.test.js

I had a quick look at their source code and it seems like you could also possibly get away with something like `bunyan.levelFromName.fatal` or `bunyan.levelFromName["fatal"]` to get the respective debugging value too.

**See:**
https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/blob/master/lib/bunyan.js#L253-L269

**Also note:**
The last few lines of the code.

module.exports.levelFromName = levelFromName;